# How do I access boolean array from another function? c++

Tags: c++, function, reference

I have a problem. I need to create a code where I can access bool array information from another function, edit the array and then send it back. I need to use a variable as the size of the array.

Global variable is not an option.

I've tried to pass it by a reference and also using structs.

code for example:

```
void x(bool (&reserved[sizeOfArray)) {
    if (reserved[1] == true) {
          cout << "it's true";

}    

main() {

int sizeOfArray = 6;
bool reserved[sizeOfArray];

x(reserved[sizeOfArray];
```

edit: the size of the array is determined when the program is already running

Comment: This is not valid C++ code.

Comment: If the array size needs to be a variable then your best option is `std::vector`, variable length arrays are not supported in C++

Comment: The name of the array is "reserved", not "reserved[sizeOfArray]". `reserved[sizeOfArray]` would be a `bool`, if it existed.

Comment: If you want to use the most readable C++ syntax : std::array<bool,6> reserved; void x(std::array<bool,6>& reserved){}

Comment: Have you tried accessing it via pointer. You can also pass array size as another function argument.

Comment: You've gotten quite a few different suggestions in the answers here. Didn't _any_ help?

Answer (score 1):

If the size is only determined at runtime, you essentially have two options:

1. Use a dynamically-sized container, like `std::vector`

   `void x(std::vector<bool>& reserved)`
2. Use the "C method" of passing a pointer to the array's first element along with the array size
   `void x(bool reserved[], size_t size)`

The possible third option of having a "sentinel" value last in the array (like C-strings) won't work with `bool`, since you only have two values to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I think the lightweight method would be to use std::span instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

void x(std::span<bool> reserved) {
    reserved[1] = false;
}    

int main() {

    constexpr size_t sizeOfArray = 6;
    bool reserved[sizeOfArray]{false, true};

    x(reserved);

    if (reserved[1] == false) {
        std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a function template, with the array size as a template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
void x(bool (&reserved)[N]) {

    // make sure that the array size is at least 2 to not get out of
    // bounds access in reserved[1]:

    if constexpr (N >= 2) {    
        if (reserved[1] == true) {
            std::cout << "it's true\n";
        }
    }
}    

int main() {
    constexpr size_t sizeOfArray = 6; // must be a constant expression
    
    bool reserved[sizeOfArray]{false,true}; // rest will be false

    x(reserved);
}
```

Output:

```
It's true
```

Comment: How about using std::span instead?

Comment: @vikram Sure, that'd work too but the above is pretty close to what OP had in his/her code already - for better or for worse.

Comment: I agree with that and I like your answer. But std::span makes the code less daunting and clearer. Perhaps just a personal opinion.

Comment: @vikram I like the `span` approach too. Oh, you added an answer for it. Here, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boost::dynamic_bitset` for dynamic vectors of bools. [[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/hjnW53xac)

```cpp
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <iostream>  // cout

void x(const boost::dynamic_bitset<>& reserved) {
    if (reserved[1] == true) {
          std::cout << "it's true\n\n";
    }
    for (int i{0}; i < reserved.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << reserved[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int sizeOfArray = 6;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> reserved(sizeOfArray, 0b111010);
    x(reserved);
}
```